# How to mock mvc method + constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

From this page http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=836, they do this:

```
public class CarDealershipController:Controller
{
  private ICarDealershipController:Controller repository;

  public CarDealershipController:Controller(
    ICarDealershipController:Controller repository)
  {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  public ActionResult List(string carid)
  {
    var cars = repository.GetCarById(carid);
    return View("List", cars);
  }
}
```

I've modified the code slightly by adding the carid parameter.  Since this class requires a value sent into its constructor, how does that work if the initial call is:

```
localhost/Home/List/carid
```

How does the constructor get initialized?

Comment: Isn't it in the link itself? Look at the constructor of the test class. I'd prefer to do that in the TestInitialize method though.

Comment: Dependency injection, specifically, constructor injection.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by testing this controller?  There does not seem to be much testable logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, i strongly recommend **Professional Test-Driven Development with C#** by  **James Bender & Jeff McWherter**

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would grab a dependecy resolver like Unity, Ninject or something similar to do this for you. You register a concrete type against any interfaces used and they will construct it and pass it to any constructors that need one.

To do this, they use a controller factory that hooks into their resolver, rather than the default controller factory, which really only likes empty constructors.

Comment: I agree with @SteveFenton. See the following article for how to do this in MVC4 http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the constructor I would reccomend using  a DI framework to help out with the constructor injection. In your test you would use a mocking framework to create an instance of the repository.

Seems like you have a typo on the Class name of the repository.